# jQuery select on changed attribute value

Tags: jquery, attributes

How can I select an element by current value updated by jQuery. For example, an element has `id=elementId` and `isDirty` attribute. Initially, `isDirty=NO`. Then an event trigger jQuery to set it to `YES`:

```
$('#elementId').setAttribute('isDirty', 'YES')
```

Then I want to select *ALL* elements whose `isDirty` attribute is set to `YES` by `$('[isDirty=YES]')`, but it doesn't work. `isDirty` seems holding the old value when selecting. After selected, and get `isDirty` value, the value shows `YES`. So, how can I select using the updated value?

Comment: Don't invent your own attributes. Use HTML5's custom data attributes instead e.g. `data-isDirty`

Answer (score 0):

To set attribute using jQuery object you need to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) function. `setAttribute()` is used with DOM object

*Use*

```
$('#elementId').attr('isDirty', 'YES')
```

*instead of*

```
$('#elementId').setAttribute('isDirty', 'YES')
```